# Cloud firestore rules - get document by it's field value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have two collections *worktimes* and *submissions*. Submission document has *uid* field.
I want to be able to update/delete worktime document when it's not signed. I want something like this:

```
match /worktimes/{document=**} {
  allow update, delete: if !isMonthSigned()
}
```

In my *isMonthSigned()* I want to look into submissions collection, choose the document which uid equals mine and than have access to it's field values. How do I get that document?
So far I'm stucked here:

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/submissions/{submission})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        function isSignedIn() {
          return request.auth != null;
        }

        function isOwner(userId) {
          return request.auth.uid == userId
        }


        match /submissions/{submission} {
          allow update, delete: if isSignedIn()
            && isOwner(resource.data.userId);
       }

     }
   }
```

Comment: I should have clarified that isMonthSigned() should check whether uid filed in submission documents is equal to my uid and month field in submission document is equal to month field in worktime document.

Comment: share snapshot of firestore nodes